# PHP Zend - Connect to SMTP timeout

Tags: php, zend-framework, email, smtp, send

Good day to all.

I have the following problem:

I have a cron that sends a request to a script that sends some mails using zend mailer.

On the test machine it worked without any problems. The problem is that on the production machine I get the following error:

```
xception 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message 'Connection timed out' in /var/www/html/site/include/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Abstract.php:254
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/bca/include/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php(167): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Abstract->_connect('tcp://182.19.13...')
#1 /var/www/html/bca/include/Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php(199): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp->connect()
#2 /var/www/html/bca/include/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp->_sendMail()
#3 /var/www/html/bca/include/Zend/Mail.php(1178): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#4 /var/www/html/bca/include/DatabaseObject/Newsletter.php(249): Zend_Mail->send()
#5 /var/www/html/bca/include/Controllers/NewsletterController.php(551): DatabaseObject_Newsletter->sendEmail('', 'f04e3ae3586c39f...')
#6 /var/www/html/bca/include/Zend/Controller/Action.php(513): NewsletterController->processAction()
#7 /var/www/html/bca/include/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('processAction')
#8 /var/www/html/bca/include/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#9 /var/www/html/bca/public_html/index.php(660): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
```

The cron that I run is:

wget -O - -t 1 https://www.site.ro/newsletter/process --no-check-certificate

or, similar,

wget -O - -t 1 http://www.site.ro/newsletter/process

First time when I received the problem I told them to check the SMTP configurations, but the ppl. that did the configuration insist that the configuration is OK. So... I don't know. It seems like a lack of connectivity but they still insist is OK. Any help pls.?

Well... I don't know what they did... but now they get this:

```
exception 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message '5.3.3 AUTH mechanism LOGIN not     available ' in /var/www/html/bca/include/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Abstract.php:408 Stack     trace:
#0 /var/www/html/bca/include/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp/Auth/Login.php(91): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Abstract->_expect(334) 
#1 /var/www/html/bca/include/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php(217): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp_Auth_Login->auth() 
#2 /var/www/html/bca/include/Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php(200): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp->helo('localhost') 
#3 /var/www/html/bca/include/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp->_sendMail() 
#4 /var/www/html/bca/include/Zend/Mail.php(1178): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail)) 
#5 /var/www/html/bca/include/DatabaseObject/Newsletter.php(249): Zend_Mail->send() 
#6 /var/www/html/bca/include/Controllers/NewsletterController.php(551): DatabaseObject_Newsletter->sendEmail('', 'f04e3ae3586c39f...') 
#7 /var/www/html/bca/include/Zend/Controller/Action.php(513): NewsletterController->processAction() 
#8 /var/www/html/bca/include/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('processAction') 
#9 /var/www/html/bca/include/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http)) 
#10 /var/www/html/bca/public_html/index.php(660): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() 
#11 {main}
```

I suggested to check user/pass... for the 7th time... they still say is ok.

Comment: And have you already checked that you can connect to the SMTP server from your production server? Because that's what is causing the timeout when you look at the stack trace...

Comment: That's what I said, but I don't have direct access and the guys that do are keep saying (and trust me I asked them about 99999 times) that all is fine.

Comment: You could ask them to check the logs, and if they don't see a connection attempt from your server then it could be a firewall related issue on your end (ie. that the server is configured not to allow outbound connections for specific - privileged - ports). Even though that should be a drop and not cause timeouts, but you never know :p.

Comment: BTW You could also test if the problem is on their end by using another SMTP server... Because if that works it's bound to be an issue on their end.

Comment: I mailed them... also I asked for logs but... it will take a while.

Answer (score 1):

I would verify that the SMTP can be contacted from your production server by running the following from a command prompt on the server:

```
$ telnet 1.2.3.4 25
```

Where 1.2.3.4 is the IP address or hostname of the SMTP server you're trying to connect to. From the exception it looks like this address starts `182.19.13...`

When you run the command you should see something like:

```
Connected to foo.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 foo ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
```

If you don't see something similar to that please post up the output/error

Comment: The smtp server is configured on the same machine.

Comment: In that case you could try changing the hostname you're connecting to - see if you have different results with the external hostname (e.g. mail.example.com or whatever it is), localhost, the external ip address or 127.0.0.1.